# Add extra_hosts to all containers

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, hosts

I have a project that can be run on multiple OSes Linux/Windows/Mac. I have single docker-compose file. For Windows and MAC docker-compose starting version 18 is smart enough to add host.docker.internal automatically into containers so I can connect the containers. For Ubuntu, I have to specify every time

```
extra_hosts:
      - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
```

Is there a way to always inject these additions to host files for the container whenever the container is created, so that it is similar to Windows and Mac?
Am I looking at this wrongly?

I just want to avoid tedious editing of the docker-compose file because docker behaves differently on Ubuntu than on Mac and Windows.

Comment: Do you have an example of a project that's actually portable across these OSes, and also needs to call back to a non-container service on the host?  (Is there some dependency you could add to the Compose setup to not need this?)

Comment: @DavidMaze I use NodeJS, so it's running on all of these platforms. I have a microservice architecture with multiple services. While developing the service I develop I run from VSCode with `npm run start` but other services are run from with docker-compose. Services need to be able to access each other.

Comment: Which part of the system is running outside a container (on all three OSes), though?  You don't need that `extra_hosts:` line just to communicate between containers (see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation).